# Using classes and functions

Tags: php

I have a question when it comes to using classes, constructors and functions

I'm trying to use json_encode and echo the array out.
Can anyone point me in the correct direction here? I don't really know what I'm doing wrong, I thought it was correct but I guess not. Any and all help is appreciated. Thanks.

No errors or output.

```
class information
{

    public $motd, $owner, $greeting;
    public $array;

    function __construct($motd, $owner, $greeting){
        $this->motd = $motd;
        $this->owner = $owner;
        $this->greeting = $greeting;
    }

    function test(){
       $array = array(
        'motd' => $motd,
        'owner' => $owner,
        'greeting' => $greeting
       );
       $pretty = json_encode($array);
       echo $pretty;
    }

}


$api = new information('lolol','losslol','lololol');
$api->test;
?>
```

Comment: You need to *call* the `test` method. `$api->test();`

Comment: and you array will be empty should be: motd' => $this->motd,
        'owner' => $this->owner,
        'greeting' => $this->greeting

Comment: Remember to *read* a lot of code, and *test* a lot more. In that way you will learn better than asking for help at the first issue.

Answer (score 3):

Two mistakes:

1. You're missing `$this`:

   ```
   $array = array(
     'motd' => $this->motd,
     'owner' => $this->owner,
     'greeting' => $this->greeting
   );
   ```
2. You need to call `$api->test()`.

   Your current code only evalutes `$api->test` (which results in a reference to a function) and throws the value away.

Comment: This was my problem, I'm sorry this was probably a waste of a post. Thank you.

Comment: @BlueFireMedia No problem, but please remember to accept an answer for every question you posted: [how does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/191400) (if there is an answer which seems sufficient for you)

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the `test` method, and you need to refer to variables correctly:

```
class information
{

    public $motd, $owner, $greeting;
    public $array;

    function __construct($motd, $owner, $greeting){
        $this->motd = $motd;
        $this->owner = $owner;
        $this->greeting = $greeting;
    }

    function test(){
       $array = array(
        'motd' => $this->motd,  // note the $this->
        'owner' => $this->owner,  // note the $this->
        'greeting' => $this->greeting  // note the $this->
       );
       $pretty = json_encode($array);
       echo $pretty;
    }

}


$api = new information('lolol','losslol','lololol');
$api->test(); // note the ()
?>
```